# pgAdmin4-desktop: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

Tags: pgadmin-4

'm working here with Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon. I just installed pgAdmin4-desktop, but when I try to run it I get this error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:.

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/andre/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - USER: andre
  - LANGUAGE: pt_BR:pt:en
  - XDG_SEAT: seat0
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
  - SSH_AGENT_PID: 1486
  - SHLVL: 0
  - HOME: /home/andre
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: cinnamon
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - MANDATORY_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: qt5ct
  - LOGNAME: andre
  - DEFAULTS_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path
  - XDG_SESSION_ID: c2
  - PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
  - GDM_LANG: pt_BR
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
  - DISPLAY: :0
  - LANG: pt_BR.UTF-8
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: cinnamon
  - XAUTHORITY: /home/andre/.Xauthority
  - XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/lightdm-data/andre
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  - SHELL: /bin/bash
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - GDMSESSION: cinnamon
  - GPG_AGENT_INFO: /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
  - XDG_VTNR: 7
  - PWD: /home/andre
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/cinnamon:/usr/share/gnome:/home/andre/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
  - XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
  - GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
  - GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING: 1
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/op-144952:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1420,unix/op-144952:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1420
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: X-Cinnamon
  - GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
  - GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
  - CINNAMON_VERSION: 4.0.10
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 30691
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 34253
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 3b64ea65-075e-4a45-9b70-ff84078ce02f
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

2022-03-22 11:01:29,374: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off

2022-03-22 11:01:30,353: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

...
```

Any idea on how can I solve this?